# Enable libmongossl in centos

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

I'm using and PHP7.0 on centos 7. How can I enable libmongoc SSL on my server?

This is my `php -i|grep mongo`

```
    mongodb
libmongoc bundled version => 1.12.0
libmongoc SSL => disabled
libmongoc crypto => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
PWD => /root/mongo-php-driver
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /root/mongo-php-driver
```

installed by using the steps followed in [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php)

Seems that `libmongoc` and `libbson` is not configured by default?

Comment: But it is for plesk...and It is not working for mw

Answer (score 1):

It is ok, i got the answer, posting here for any further reference.

```
sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
sudo yum install pecl
sudo yum install gcc
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

This steps need to be followed inorder to enable libmongoc

You can check whether they are enabled using the below command

`php -i | grep mongo`

```
mongodb
libmongoc bundled version => 1.12.0
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => enabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Thank you for attempting for the rest of the people